# Default number of threads in selecehiveql processor nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

What is the default threads execution of SelectHiveQL processor in nifi and in general default threads of a nifi processor.

I have concurrent tasks set to 0 in the scheduling tab but still i can see in the logs that more than one thread does the parsing of the sql statements

Answer (score 2):

If you have concurrent tasks set to 0, then you must have selected an Event-Driven scheduling strategy. If you have a number of FlowFiles available in the incoming queue, multiple threads/tasks will be created to handle the incoming queue as long as FlowFiles are available. From the User's Guide section on the [Scheduling Tab](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab), "the number of threads is limited only by the size of the Event-Driven Thread Pool that the administrator has configured."

Comment: no I am using timer driven with run schedule as 3600 . Still I can see in the logs that select query is being parsed multiple times .



2018-05-15 06:29:54,919 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver Parsing command: select * from random 2018-05-15 06:29:54,919 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver Parse Completed 2018-05-15 06:29:55,063 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver Parsing command: select * from random

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your scheduling tab and the tab with the configuration properties such as Query?

Comment: If you're using timer-driven then concurrent tasks should be at least 1? What are the time units on your run schedule of 3600? Seconds, milliseconds, etc.? The time difference between parsing is 144 millis but it appears to be a single thread, does the SELECT statement complete successfully? Are multiple flow files being issued?

Comment: If you're using timer-driven then concurrent tasks should be at least 1? What are the time units on your run schedule of 3600? Seconds, milliseconds, etc.? The time difference between parsing is 144 millis but it appears to be a single thread, does the SELECT statement complete successfully? Are multiple flow files being issued?

Comment: I some how managed to get the answer to this .  It depends on the fetch size you are putting in the properties of the processor . larger the fetch size less parsing of the sql executions , smaller the fetch size is proportionate to the number of sql statements being issues with the run schedule frequency .